# Incremental powers of elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to take the power of each element in an incremental way, i.e. for an input `x = [6,9,5]` I want my output to be `y = [6², 9³, 5⁴]`, the power starts from a given variable `p`.

My code:

```
var sqr = [];
var n = [6,9,5];
var p = 2;
 for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      for (let j = p; j < n.length + 1; j++) {
        sqr.push(Math.pow(n[i],j));
        console.log(sqr);
        i++;
     }
return sqr;
```

It works but never execute the last elements depending on the size of the array and/or `p` (I know it's because it goes to an index which doesn't exists). But I'm wondering if there's a better way that works. Thanks

Comment: Your current code is missing at least a `}`. Also, what is `num`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's probably missing it since it's only a portion of code in a function i made to do something else, num is supposed to be the array n. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use one loop.  You can increment the power `p` inside the loop.

```js
var sqr = [];
var n = [6,9,5];
var p = 2;
for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {    
    sqr.push(Math.pow(n[i],p));    
    p++; 
}
console.log(sqr);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `.map` (to transform one array into another) and the exponentiation operator `**` instead. Take the index of the element being iterated over (the second argument of the callback) to figure out how large the exponent should be:

```js
var n = [6,9,5];
const powers = n.map((num, i) => num ** (i + 2));
console.log(powers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var sqr = [];
var n = [6,9,5];
n.map((v, i) => sqr.push(v ** (i+2)));
console.log(sqr);
```

Read about `map` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Basically, `map` goes through each element in an array through a function that contains the parameters `v` and `i`. `v` is the current value being run by `map` and `i` is the index of the value in the array. At index 0, you want to square the number, at index 1 cube it, and at index 2 power to 4. There is a constant rate of variation which is `power = index + 2`. That's what `i+2` is. The rest should be self-explanatory.

Comment: If you are going to use `.map` for iterating only (and not use its return value) you might as well use `.forEach` which is designed for that purpose (where `.map()` shouldn't be causing side-effects)